# Unsolved Problem asked as a question in math.se

Tags: discussion, editing

What are the guidelines?  Will the moderators take action OR does someone have to flag it as "Known Unsolved Problem" or "Known Open Problem".

For instance [question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123994/triplets-based-equation) was about a Diophantine Equation that is listed as Unsolved.

Comment: That is one reason I go about asking people posting number-theory related questions for the source of the problem...

Comment: There also is the [tag:open-problem] tag.

Answer (score 11):

I think that an answer explaining that this is an open problem and perhaps listing a few sources for that (and maybe conjectures on the possible answers) should be a good step, no need to alert the moderators.

Comment: I wonder if we're talking about a situation where OP *knows* it's a known unsolved problem and withholds that information. I could see where the moderators might want to know about such behavior.

Comment: @Gerry: yes, and it would be ironic if we can get a new closure reason "closed as 'known open problem'".

Comment: I can imagine the topologists saying, "Sure, a question can be simultaneously open and closed, what's the problem?"

Comment: @RahulNarain: Let $\alpha<\omega_1$ can we find a question which is $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ but not $\Sigma^0_\beta$ for all $\beta<\alpha$?

Comment: @RahulNarain Your last comment was hilarious, even if it is incorrect. :-)